# How to mark a checkbox in the related opportunity from a quote button?

Tags: javascript, button, quote

I am trying to mark a checkbox via a javascript button, i.e. update it as true. The checkbox is a field (Precisa_Cota_o_Frete__c) in the opportunity, but I want the button to work from the quote detail page. Here is the code I've got so far, but I am getting an error message from Salesforce:

Code:

```
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js")} 
{!REQUIRESCRIPT("/soap/ajax/20.0/apex.js")} 

 var opportunity = sforce.connection.query("Select Opportunityid From Quote where id = '{!Quote.Id}'");
 var myJob1 = new sforce.SObject("Opportunity"); 
 myJob1.Id = opportunity; 
 myJob1.Precisa_Cota_o_Frete__c = "true"; 
 var result = sforce.connection.update([myJob1]); 
 window.location.reload();
```

> **Error Message:** A problem with the OnClick JavaScript for this button
>   or link was encountered:
>
> {faultcode:'soapenv:Client', faultstring:'Unexpected element
>   {urn:partner.soap.sforce.com}done during simple type deserialization',
>   line:'1015', column:'29',
>   sourceURL:'https://na23.salesforce.com/soap/ajax/20.0/connection.js',
>   }

It already does work without the var opportunity part on the opportunity page, there just defining the Id by putting myJob1.Id =  "{!Opportunity.Id }";

Any ideas? Is that cross-referencing at all possible?

Comment: Why you try to use JS in this example?

Comment: I couldn't find a way to mark a checkbox via URL, if that is the question.

Comment: As I understand you mean mark/update in database

Comment: Yes, that is correct. - I want to update the checkbox field Precisa_Cota_o_Frete__c to the value true. The field is in the Opportunity. The button should work from the quote page.

Comment: If you don't want to write too much javascript, you could write an apex method with the webservice annotation, and then just use javascript to call the function.

Answer (score 2):

This should be possible. Try removing the quotation marks around **true** in your code. The field will be expecting a boolean value, and you're attempting to assign a string.

So the line in question becomes:

```
myJob1.Precisa_Cota_o_Frete__c = true;
```

Comment: The way I programmed the button actually works already on the opportunity, it seems to have accepted it with quotation marks there, although your comment makes sense! My difficulty is how to cross-reference quote/opportunity correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Java script button is also quite nice solution, but I think you should try page + controller.
Create vf page with controller that will contain method to update parent opportunity - define this action in page.
Call page from button and add button to quote layout.

I think it is safer to use standard solutions than JS.

Comment: I've always been torn between which is the best way of doing this. Using a visualforce page feels like the more proper "salesforce" way to do it, but on my org, I feel that it is noticeably slower than javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Change your 6 line to:

```
myJob1.Id = opportunity.records[0].Opportunityid;
```

The `sforce.connection.query` method doesn't return the specified field, but rather a `List<SObject>`.